# TableLayout divide space without stretching the button?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want the buttons to be their original size (wrap content), but them to be aligned in that logical cell location. Is that possible? I mean, I want something like,

```
|[Lisa]_______|[Simpson]____|
```

not,

```
|[___Lisa____]|[__Simpson__]|
```

or,

```
|[Lisa]|[Simpson]___________|
```

The following code did not work.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Lisa"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Simpson"/>
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: you want the text on buttons to stick to right side, right?

Comment: If I am getting you correctly, no. I want the text to be on the middle of the button, isn't that how it works by default?

Comment: oh, now I got that. You need to put the button into some container (some layout), and then set the weight to the container

Comment: Actually, I thought of that first, but it did not seem efficient to nest a lot of layouts, so I was wondering if there is a better way. Do you think I should use something other than the TableLayout for this?

Comment: I don't see much sense in using TableLayout for this task

Comment: Could you name an alternative layout?

Comment: I'd use just LinearLayout with weights

Answer (score 0):

`TableLayout` centers its items by default. What you can use is a `LinearLayout`, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Lisa"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Simpson"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This divides the space of the two buttons evenly, but does not center each button. This is how it looks.

[image]